# Computationally elegant and robust way to find specific point within dataset

Tags: matlab

[image]
[image]
I would like to extract the x coordinates of the marked points with Matlab. The data is already normalized and smoothed (matlab fcn smoothdata(y, 'sgolay', 'Degree', 2, 'SamplePoints', x)). The datasamples are nonuniform.

I thought about finding the starting point of the first rising edge, and connecting a straight line towards a samplepoint of the falling edge. Then iterating over the points on the falling edge until I get a crossing between the straight line and the point of interest.
[image]
However this does not seem very elegant and might not be the most robust way of finding the changepoint.

Can anyone help me guide into a more robust and elegant direction?

Thanks!

Edit:
Here are some Pictures of first and second derivatives
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

It kind of works calculating the second derivative and then looking for the maximum within the area of 0.2 and 0.55. Thanks to @MarcusMüller.

```
f2 = gradient(gradient(yy(:,ii)));
[~, idx_start] = min(abs(xx(:,ii)-0.2));
[~, idx_end]   = min(abs(xx(:,ii)-0.55));
[~, ptidx]     = max(f2(idx_start:idx_end,1));
ptidx          = ptidx+idx_start-1;
```

However this is not very robust, especially the endpoint of the window might be too narrow. Can I improve this somehow?

Answer (score 2):

The point you're looking for seems to be an inflection point, where the first derivative changes from being falling to being rising. If you consider your curve as continuous, that means it has a zero second derivative.

You can [numerically approximate the second derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Higher-order_differences) and then look for values close to zero in the resulting time series.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I looked into that before smoothing the data. Apparently I forgot about it after smoothing it...